# adding a second if else statement to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure like below which works fine.

```
declare db_cursor cursor for
select Atmosphere, Region, PreATR
from myTbl

open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @Atmosphere, @Region, @PreATR


while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

   if @PreATR = 1
      set @q = 'insert into tblA ... '       
   else
      set @q = 'insert into tblB ...
   end

   exec(@q)

   fetch next from db_cursor into @Atmosphere, @Region, @PreATR
end

close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

However now I need to adjust it. So I want to add another if else statement like below. When I do this though the line below becomes highlighted

> close db_cursor
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'close'. expecting CONVERSATION

```
    open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @Atmosphere, @Region, @PreATR


while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

   if @Region = 55
      set @someVar = 1
   else
      set @someVar = 1
   end

   if @PreATR = 1
      set @q = 'insert into tblA ... '       
   else
      set @q = 'insert into tblB ...
   end

   exec(@q)

   fetch next from db_cursor into @Atmosphere, @Region, @PreATR
end

close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

why does adding this extra if else statement cause this behavior?

Comment: you are sure the first query works fine ? I see a mismatch in `BEGIN` and `END` . By the way the syntax for `IF .. ELSE` does not have an `END` keyword. Refer to doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Remove `end` after `set @someVar = 1` and after `set @q = 'insert into tblB ...`

Comment: thanks, i didn't realise if else statements don't have an end block, apologies I should have checked that

Comment: You should consider re-write that using set-based approach. Cursor in general is slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because if else syntax was incorrect and also single quote was missing in the second insert statement, try below-updated query, I have removed end after else statement and added a single quote in the second insert statement -

```
open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @Atmosphere, @Region, @PreATR


while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

   if @Region = 55
      set @someVar = 1
   else
      set @someVar = 1


   if @PreATR = 1
      set @q = 'insert into tblA ... '       
   else
      set @q = 'insert into tblB ...'


   exec(@q)

   fetch next from db_cursor into @Atmosphere, @Region, @PreATR
end

close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

Note: Whenever there are multiple statements with if and else block then you must use begin and end like below -

```
IF @Var = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT '1';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'not 1';
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Im sure you could do this much simpler and faster without a cursor, unfortunate there is not enough details in the question to write an example that can get you started

probably you need something like this

```
insert into tblA (your fields here)
select t.Atmosphere, t.Region, t.PreATR
from   myTbl t
where  t.PreATR = 1
and    more conditions here...

insert into tblB (your fields here)
select t.Atmosphere, t.Region, t.PreATR
from   myTbl t
where  t.PreATR <> 1
and    more conditions here...
```